# display value of series and y axis data together in tooltip template kendo UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I am using kendo UI Bar chart to display some data.
I am able to display the column chart..

But I have some concern If any body can help.

1. I don't want ant gap between low voltage data bar and high voltage data bar
2. How to display value of series and y axis data together in tooltip template

[image]

I want it to be

[image]
Please find attached images for reference..

My code:

```
title: {
},
legend: {
    position: "bottom"
},
seriesDefaults: {
    type: "column",
//stack: true
},
series: [{
    name: "# Low Voltage Service Points",
    data: [50, 23, 74, 20, 20, 10],
    color: "#1A5FED",

    // Line chart marker type
    markers: {
        type: "square"
    }
}, {
    name: "# High Voltage Service Points",
    data: [52, 34, 78, 68, 23, 40],
    color: "#ed3024",
}],
valueAxis: {
    line: {
        visible: false
    },
    labels: {
    //format: "{0}%"
    },
    axisCrossingValue: 0
},
categoryAxis: {
    categories: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"],
    color: "#ff0000",
    majorGridLines: {
        visible: false
    },
    line: {
        visible: false
    },
    labels: {
        template: "#=categories[value]#"
    },
},
tooltip: {
    visible: true,
    format: "{0}",
    template: "#= series.name #: #= value #, Date"
}
```

My code is working fine..

Thanks!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To avoid spaces use "spacing" parameter in the series

```
series: [{
        spacing: 0,
}]
```

to show the category value in the tooltip use this #= category #

```
 template: "#= series.name #: #= category # = #= value # "
```

I have Done a Jsfidle Example so you can see it in action

http://jsfiddle.net/chanaka1/hy7uqu00/2/

Hope this helps.

Comment: How to show only min value and max value in x-axis.. If u can help....  I have ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"], in categories but I just want to display Jan and in last Jun in x- axis. But tooltip should work properly..  can u help ?

Comment: use a template with if condition , check if Jan and Jun if so show the category if not don't show